# How to do conditional debugging in make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm looking to instrument my makefiles to have some conditional messages.   A simple example of what I'd like would look something like this:

```
ifdef DEBUG_XX
define info_xx
$$(info XX $(1))
endef
else
info_xx :=
endif

some_var := 1
$(info def:$(call info_xx, called: some_var:$(some_var)))
$(call info_xx,called: some_var:$(some_var))

all:
```

Such that my message shows up if and only if `DEBUG_XX` is defined.  Unfortunately, the above throws an error:

```
make-lib> make -f test.mk DEBUG_XX=y
def:$(info XX  called: some_var:1)
test.mk:11: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

It seems to be evaluating the output of the `$(info)`, which doesn't make much sense to me...  What am I missing?

Comment: You may take a look at https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-verbosestring0string1string2string3string4string5string6string7string8string9 , maybe it is what you want?

Comment: Not really --  The above is a simple example, but I have a much more complicated scenario in mind.  I need to understand why the simple stuff is failing before I can go forward...

Comment: But you understand why the second call to `info_xx` fails?

Comment: No, that's what I was missing. though I think i've figured it out now.  I was assuming that the defines were 'simply expanded', -- that is, the define would be defined, call would expand it, and make would evaluate the expanded version.   But it appears as though they are recursively expanded.   Therefore the `$$` is causing the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to double-dollar before "info", which is a mistake: a line inside "define"/"endef" is saved as a literal which becomes expanded only at the substitution operator(s).

However, IMO, it's better to rewrite your code like this:

```
info_xx=$(if $(DEBUG_XX),$(info XX $1))
```

Also note that:

```
$(info def:$(call info_xx, called: some_var:$(some_var)))
```

will print

```
XX called: some_var:1
def:
```

That's because the argument expansion (i.e. "call" and then the 2nd "info") is done before the 1st "info" will have a chance to print anything.

You can fix it with `info_xx=$(if $(DEBUG_XX),XX $1)`. But then a pure `$(call info_xx,called: some_var:$(some_var))` will obviously result in error.